# Finding matching values across columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Is there a built-in function that allows for selecting only rows that have matching column values in pandas?

As an example, I have a pandas dataframe that is composed of columns of users, each movie item they have rated, and the rating they have given it (see below). Is there a way using numpy or pandas to quickly select only the movies that both users have rated? In other words, output a list/array/dataframe of all movies that have been rated by the user in question (a) and every other user?

In the example below, all users have rated movie 7. Therefore for a query of user (a)=8 would ideally output the all the common ratings for this user and every other one.

```
user    movie   rating
8        7        5.0
8       1333      3.0
50      3321      1.0
50      3363      2.0
50        7       3.0
83       50       4.0
83       7        5.0
etc      etc      etc

output for user 8
50        7       3.0
83       7        5.0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps something like:

```
In [11]: df.loc[(df["user"] != 8) & (df["movie"].isin(df.loc[(df.user == 8), "movie"]))]
Out[11]:
   user  movie  rating
4    50      7     3.0
6    83      7     5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want all users who have rated movie 7, except 8:

```
df[(df["movie"].isin(df.loc[(df.user == 8), "movie"])) & (df.user!=8)]
```

This is slightly faster than Andy's answer below:

```
%%timeit 
df[(df["movie"].isin(df.loc[(df.user == 8), "movie"])) & (df.user!=8)]
1.13 ms ± 54.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%%timeit 
df.loc[(df["user"] != 8) & (df["movie"].isin(df.loc[(df.user == 8), "movie"]))]
1.21 ms ± 110 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Comment: I think this misses the important part of looking up which movies user 8 has reviewed e.g. maybe also 1333.

Comment: Thanks @AndyHayden. Didn't realize that's the case.